# JavaScript That Reads Data From HTML Table

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to develop a program, using JavaScript, that can read, and compile, data from an HTML table.

The end goal is to identify, and display, the number of marked (filled in) fields in each row, then display it in numerical data.

If you can help me understand this, please do.

Hope this explains it, and I'll answer questions if you have them.

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") **must include** the desired behavior, a specific problem or error **and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself**. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example.](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can retrieve your table using the HTML Table id and do the processing of each cell value as below. You need to apply the apply transformations to the cell value in terms of Integer or Float or whatever numeric format you want to apply to the cell values.

```
<table id="cTable">
    <tr>
        <td>L1</td>
        <td>L2</td>
        <td>L3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>M1</td>
        <td>M2</td>
        <td>M3</td>
    </tr>
</table>

<script>
    //get the table using the Table id
    var mTable = document.getElementById('cTable');

    //get the number of rows of the table
    var rowLen = mTable.rows.length;

    //loop through rows    
    for (i = 0; i < rowLen; i++){
      //gets number of cells of current row  
       var rowCells = mTable.rows.item(i).cells;

       //get the amount of cells of current row
       var cellLen = rowCells.length;

       //loop through each cell in the current row
       for(var j = 0; j < cellLen; j++){

              // get your cell info here
              var cellVal = rowCells.item(j).innerHTML;

              // You can do the appropriate processing of numerical values below.
              alert(cellVal); 
           }
    }
</script>
```